# Less code for '+' css selector

Tags: css, less

I was working with custom radio buttons and checkboxes, the css is vast so I want to convert it to less way of organizing but how can I convert this statement to less

```
 input[type='checkbox']:checked + .mycheck-overlay:before{
       /*some css*/
 }
```

any help would be greatfull....

Comment: Please ask a question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you want to structure your LESS, the following is still valid, if you dont need any styling for the intermediate sections.

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked + .mycheck-overlay:before{
     /*some css*/
}
```

However, depending on exactly which section of the rule you wish to style, in full you can break it down thusly:

```
input[type='checkbox']{
    /* normal checkbox styles */
    &:checked{
       /* checked state checkbox styles */
       + .mycheck-overlay{
          /* style of elements with class mycheck-overlay immediately after a checked input checkbox */
          &:before{
             /* the before psuedo styling for those... */
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Note that you can use the ampersand `&` character preceding a nested rule to indicate it should be applied [in conjunction with the parent selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules) (i.e. when the rule is compiled, no space should be left between it and the preceding selector)